# How stop device Orientation into Landscape Mode in UIViewController With UINavigationBarController and UITabbarController

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

How to stop device Orientation into Landscape Mode in UIViewController With UINavigationBarController + UITabbarController.

Answer (score 0):

Its up to individual view controllers to decide if they'd like to auto-rotate. Container view controllers (like UINavigationController, tab-bar controller or one of your own) typically delegate to their children to decide this. Add/override these methods on your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

One is the older style and one is the iOS6+ style.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to competently remove orientations for your app in xcode you can set supported orientations
[image]